# Sending html received from form to email securely with php

Tags: php, security, filtering

I have a button to send a div as html to email on a website.
I would like to avoid rebuilding the html using just the variables associated but I think about the risk of doing this as someone could send anything to my php script.
Also is it enough to remove `<script>` tags ?

This is how I get and send the email:

```
    $subject = 'Some title';
    $message = $html_mail;
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'To: '. $to . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: My name <'.$admin_mail.'>' . "\r\n";
    $response = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all the email clients such as gmail, yahoo, outlook, thunderbird, mail etc do not run javascript at all. Javascript and other scripts are disabled by default. So `<script>` tags are not at all security threat. However, abusive language or images that users might embed in HTML emails can be a serious issue in your case if it is not handled appropriately. If you think that your users are sophisticated and it is not the case then there are no worries.

Comment: So if I understand the problem can only be the content itself (pornographic image, insult...) ?

Comment: Other than content itself. HTML is safe to be sent in emails